# Testing if a value is in either one of two lists

Tags: python

I have one area in my code that checks if item of one list is in other two lists and return a result depending on that.

Apparently, first IF clause is always true and only result from that clause is returned.

Here is the example:

```
from datetime import date

days = [date(2018, 9, 10), date(2018, 9, 11), date(2018, 9, 12)]
list_one = [date(2018, 9, 13), date(2018, 9, 14), date(2018, 9, 15)]
list_two = [date(2018, 9, 8), date(2018, 9, 9), date(2018, 9, 10)]

for day in days:

   if day not in(list_one, list_two):
       print('Case one')
   elif day in list_one:
       print('Case two')
   elif day in list_two:
       print('Case three')
```

Comment: you're checking if `day` is (not) in the tuple `(list_one, list_two)`, when I suspect you wish to check whether `day` is in either of the `list`s.

Comment: What did you expect `if day not in (list_one, list_two)` to mean? Is it "if `day` is in `list_one` *or* `list_two`" or "if `day` is in `list_one` *and* `list_two`"?

Comment: You can only check if a *whole list* is in a tuple of lists, such as `list_one in (list_one, list_two)`, `list_two in (list_one, list_two)`, `[date(2018, 9, 13), date(2018, 9, 14), date(2018, 9, 15)] in (list_one, list_two)`, etc.

Comment: Your first if compares a single day against each list of days, not against the days in the lists. And a day can never be a list of days

Comment: Srđan, if your question has been answered please consider accepting one of the answers by clicking the green checkmark next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

`(list_one, list_two)` is a tuple of exactly *two* elements, containing `list_one` and `list_two`. Since a `day` is never equal to a list, `day not in (list_one, list_two)` turns out to be True.

You could either merge the lists and write

```
lists = list_one + list_two
if day not in lists:
    ...
```

or use

```
if day not in list_one and day not in list_two:
    ...
```

or alternatively, applying [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
if not (day in list_one or day in list_two):
    ...
```

to express that `day` is in neither of those lists.

Comment: I'd also recommend using `set` and `set.union`, as there are repeated lookups here.

Comment: @jpp using sets is often a good optimization when the items are hashable, but I'll stick with the lists here because explaining to OP why the code does not work and how to fix it with minimal changes seems more important than the optimizaton that looks quite different.

Comment: Sure, to be clear the items here *are* hashable. Sometimes it's worth a reminder that underlying a `datetime` object is an integer.

Answer (score 3):

Change the first `if` to

```
if day not in list_one + list_two
```

Currently you don't have a list of elements, you have a tuple of two lists. So, to be `in` it, the element has to be one of those lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import date

days = [date(2018, 9, 10), date(2018, 9, 11), date(2018, 9, 12)]
list_one = [date(2018, 9, 13), date(2018, 9, 14), date(2018, 9, 15)]
list_two = [date(2018, 9, 8), date(2018, 9, 9), date(2018, 9, 10)]

for day in days:
    if (day not in list_one and day  not in list_two):
        print('Case one')
    elif day in list_one:
        print('Case two')
    elif day in list_two:
        print('Case three')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have two `if` blocks testing if `day` is in either lists, for your purpose it's a easier (and more efficient) to simply use the `else` block for the case where `day` is in neither lists:

```
if day in list_one:
    print('Case two')
elif day in list_two:
    print('Case three')
else:
    print('Case one')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or `any`, to check if any elements are true, iterate trough the two list `[list_one,list_two]` if one of them are it will be true because using `in` will declare a Boolean statement:

```
...
if any(day in i for i in [list_one,list_two]):
    ...
...
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @hellow Edited mine